# How to do a cacheable redirection?

Tags: php, redirects, 301-redirect, cache, 302-redirect

When users enter my website `example.com`, their "preferred" language is detected and they are redirected (using a 301 Moved Permanently redirection) to `example.com/en/` (for English), `example.com/it/` (for Italian), etc.

It works perfectly, but when I analyzed my website with the Google Page Speed tool it gave me [the following advice](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/mobile#CacheLandingPageRedirects).

> Many pages, especially mobile pages, redirect users to a different URL, for instance from `www.example.com` to `m.example.com`. Making this redirect cache-able by the user's browser can speed up page load times for repeat visitors to a site.

And later it says

> We recommend using a 302 redirect with a cache lifetime of one day. The redirect should include a Vary: User-Agent header as well as a Cache-Control: private header.

So my questions are, how can I do a "cache-able" redirection in PHP? Would the following be enough?

```
header("HTTP/1.0 302 Moved Temporarily");
header("Location: example.com/whatever");
exit;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
header("HTTP/1.0 302 Moved Temporarily");
header("Location: example.com/whatever");
header("Cache-Control: private");
header("Vary: User-Agent, Accept-Encoding");
exit;
```

The recommendation for the Vary header is [from this google developer page](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/caching) about optimizing caches (and problems with some IE < 9). Background on [caching negotiated responses](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html#sec13.6) from RFC2616 (Header Field Definitions) where you will also find background on the Cache-control-private. A further discussion about the Vary: Header also amongst others on [this stackoverflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975416/trying-to-understand-the-vary-http-header).

You might also find useful: [Multi-regional and multilingual sites](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=182192) and [working with multilingual websites](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.de/2010/03/working-with-multilingual-websites.html).

Comment: Responding to the specific question + documentation to back it up: great answer man. Thank you very much